# Join an external worker node to a GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to have GKE manage nodes outside of its managed node pools? e.g. GCE instances spun up in a separate GCP project, AWS EC2 instances, etc.

AFAICT there's no way to run `kubeadm` on GKE to get the necessary tokens for me to run `kubeadm join` on the external nodes.

Comment: No, everything over GKE is managed by the GCP control plane. You will need to spin up a VM control plane apart.

Comment: for the greater visibility of the community I'll put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is No, because everything over GKE is managed by the GCP control plane. You will need to spin up a VM control plane apart.